# How to make the discord bot repeat the song playback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot to repeat the song playback. Assuming the variable count contains the number of times I want times I want the song to repeat, how do I make this command `voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio))`  repeat for n times, making sure that each repetition occurs only after the song is played completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`VoiceClient.play()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=play#discord.VoiceClient.play) has a `after` argument that you can use to play again audio:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import run_coroutine_threadsafe as rct

bot = commands.Bot(prefix='your_prefix')

def play_next(ctx, audio, msg, n):
    if n:
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        rct(msg.edit(content='Finished playing the song, {n} more to go.'), bot.loop)
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: play_next(ctx, audio, msg, n-1))
        voice.is_playing()
    else:
        rct(msg.delete())

@bot.command()
repeat(ctx, n):
    audio = 'your_audio_source'
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    msg = await ctx.send(f'Started playing video {n} times')
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(audio), after=lambda e: play_next(ctx, audio, msg, n-1))
    voice.is_playing()

bot.run('your_token')
```

PS: There is no error management in this code, you'll have to do your own.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I am getting this error. `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. How do I fix it?

Comment: My bad, I took some of my code ^^. You just have to remove `self.` from `voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` and `run_coroutine_threadsafe(ctx.send('Finished playing the song, {n} more to go.'), self.bot.loop)`.

Comment: How do I delete the message sent in `ctx.send('Finished playing the song, {n} more to go.')` in the next iteration? I am trying to keep the discord message clean where only one message will be displayed.

Comment: I changed the code so it will send one message, edit it and delete it once it's finished :)

Comment: Would be great if you tell what `voice.is_playing()` command does

Comment: It's a way to indicate if the bot is currently playing audio or not. It can be usefull if you make a queue system.

Comment: Also the way my bot works is a bit different, where the song is played by ``p songname`, only after which the user ca set loop. However. as the song is already being played, an error is thrown on my compiler cause of which i have to use `voice.stop()` before playing the song again in my loop. Any way how I can wait until the song is completely finished and then start the loop? PS: I know I'm asking too many questions here, so can we talk about this via mail,etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220680/discussion-between-sathvik-k-s-and-mr-spaar).

Comment: I did think of `play songname 1`. But if the songname has space in it, then how is it possible to take the parameter 1? ex `play some song name 1`
Also, what is the correct way of using `bot.wait_for()`? Is it `bot.wait_for(voice.stop())`?